# sql query to truncate columns which are above specified length

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in postgres:

```
create table1 (col1 character varying, col2 character varying);
```

My table has the following data:

```
col1            col2
Questions       Tags Users
Value1          Value2 Val
```

I want find the length of col1 and col2 and when the length of values of column 1 and column2 exceeds 6, I want to truncate it and discard the remaining values. i.e. I want my final table to look like the following:

```
col1            col2
Questi          Tags U
Value1          Value2
```

Actually the reason why I want to do this is, when I create index on table1 then I am getting the following error:

> ERROR:  index row size 2744 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "allstrings_string_key"
>   HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
>   Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

I know I can do this by importing the values to some programming language and then truncating the value. Is there some way by which I may achieve the same using an sql query in postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just update them to contain only strings of length 6 at max?

I am no postrgres pro, so this is probably not the best method, but should do the job anyways:

```
UPDATE table1 SET col1 = SUBSTRING(col1, 1, 6) WHERE LEN(col1) > 6
UPDATE table1 SET col2 = SUBSTRING(col2, 1, 6) WHERE LEN(col2) > 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you actually follow the advice from Postgres, rather than changing your data. Clearly, that column with a 2k character long string shouldn't be indexed -- or not with a btree index anyway.

If the idea behind the index is searching, use full text search instead:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html

If the idea behind the need is for sorting, use a functional index instead. For instance:

```
create index tbl_sort on (substring(col from 1 for 20));
```

Then, instead of ordering by `col`, order by `substring(col from 1 for 20)`.

Comment: Actually the data beyond 2712 is  not of much use to me..therefore i want to truncate

Comment: In that just run the update: `update tbl set col = substring(col from 1 for 6)`. But methinks you should also look into that index and why it's there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the type of the column to `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`?

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ALTER COLUMN col1 SET DATA TYPE CHAR(6),
    ALTER COLUMN col2 SET DATA TYPE CHAR(6)
```

If you need the column to be variable length, you can specify a limit (note that this is a PostgreSQL extension):

```
ALTER TABLE table1
    ALTER COLUMN col1 SET DATA TYPE CHARACTER VARYING(6),
    ALTER COLUMN col2 SET DATA TYPE CHARACTER VARYING(6)
```

Comment: Bad idea: 1. CHAR has different semantics than VARCHAR. 2. Lose data.

Comment: The OP wanted to truncate the data (i.e. data would be lost anyways, as in the example provided).

Comment: I am getting syntax error at or near "DATA". Thanks a lot for replying :)

Comment: @AliceEverett I had a typo which has now been fixed. Try now (whichever version meets your needs best).